# Android DK Trying to show/hide part of the UI via Fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

So I am very new to the Android DK, and was sailing pretty fine until I started trying to mess with Fragments.

At the core of it, what I'm trying to do is have a series of buttons on my app's screen, and whichever button the user presses will change what text/spinners/buttons display on the screen.

How I decided to implement that was via Fragments. I can't figure out why my Fragment isn't displaying however, this should be a relatively simple example.

I had a activity_main.xml that is relatively simple.  I've changed variable names, but see below:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/mainActivity" 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:animateLayoutChanges="true" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonD"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/d_name"
    android:onClick="dMenuButton" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonR"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/r_name"
    android:onClick="rButton" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And the corresponding MainActivity.java

```
public void dMenuButton(View view){

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.show(dFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        dFragment = new DFragment();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, dFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }

}
```

And the fragment_d.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/text1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/numD"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/text1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/text1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With its respective DFragment.java

```
public class DFragment extends Fragment {

static Spinner dSpinner;
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dAdapter;
RelativeLayout view;

public static DFragment newInstance() {
    DFragment dFragment = new DFragment();

    return dFragment ;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_d,
                                 container, false);

    createSpinners();

    return view;
}

private void createSpinners() {

    dSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.numD);
    dAdapter= ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                                                     R.array.numD,
                                                     android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

}

}
```

Currently, the fragment layout is covering up the buttons beneath it.  Any help in forcing it to push down the components below would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are definitely on the right track with the visibility of the `fragment_container`. You could leave that as visible constantly, then allow the fragment transactions to change what is being displayed in that container.

Depending on your requirements, you could simply perform a `.replace(R.layout.fragment_container, anotherFragment)` to change which fragment is being displayed (code is pseudo only).

As for the buttons, are you adding them to the `activity_main.xml` or are they being added in the fragment's layout? As long as you add the new buttons/text after the `fragment_container` layout in the main activity layout, you should be fine. Let me know exactly what you are trying to achieve with the buttons/text!

Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on using .replace to swap the fragments out as need be.

I'm adding the buttons to the activity_main.xml.  I'd like the buttons to show their respective fragments underneath them, and push any remaining buttons down further.  Instead, when they display their fragment, they're covering up all the buttons beneath.

I added code to show the fragments to the button (which is working) and added buttons to the xml, which show up properly while the fragment is not displayed, but get covered (I'm guessing) when the fragment is displayed.

Comment: I tried using invalidate on the layout, via the following:

    (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainActivity).invalidate();

But that doesn't seem to fix it either.

Comment: Even switching everything over to a relative layout doesn't fix the issue.  It seems that the fragment draws over the other buttons rather than redrawing the entire layout, and using invalidate() doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: What is happening on the `OnClick` of the buttons? I can see that you are using `FragmentTransaction.show()`, but how are you 'pushing' the other buttons down further? Could you edit your question to show the buttons added in? I need to figure out where they are in xml or code to see why they would be overwritten.

Comment: I'm not manually pushing the buttons down further, so maybe that's my problem.  I assumed that designating the new buttons as "below" the layout containing the fragment would force them to move down if the layout changed.

Comment: No I think you're right, I just wanted to understand what was going on. I'll get back to you when I can spin up a test app. The joys of layouts!